# Understanding ActionListener

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener

I just started getting my head around Java itself and Java Swing and I have some problems understanding the "Action Listener" concept. People say that C# and Java is very alike, but that's another story when you actually try out both of them and compare.

I have the following auto-generated Action Listener for a button:

```
btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
    {
        lblNylabel.setText("New label text");
    }
});
```

I understand it like this:

1. You call a non-static method via the object "btnNewButton" **btnNewButton.addActionListener()**
2. The method takes one ActionListener instance as an argument
3. The automated code instansiates an ActionListener instance via the "new ActionListener()" constructor call - What I don't understand is that I can't instansiate the ActionListener class myself, but it's possible as an argument in the method call??
4. A "actionPerformed" method is generated inside the new instance body and used here (What?)
5. Inside the "actionPerformed" method you define what to do, when the button is clicked - Makes perfectly sense

Is it possible to do this in a more understanding/simple way that could help me understand the ActionListener concept?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> ***What I don't understand is that I can't instansiate the ActionListener class myself, but it's possible as an argument in the method call??***

When you do

```
new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        lblNylabel.setText("New label text");
   }
}
```

You're actually creating an instance of an [anonymous subclass](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/java-ent/jnut/ch03_12.htm) of `ActionListener`.

It is semantically equivalent of doing

```
class AnonymousActionListener implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        lblNylabel.setText("New label text");
   }
}

btnNewButton.addActionListener(new AnonymousActionListener());
```

(And tada, as a bonus, you just learned that you can have [*method local classes*](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/java-ent/jnut/ch03_11.htm) in Java ;-)

---

Here are a few common alternatives:

1. Use an **separate ordinary class**:

   ```
   class MyActionListener implements ActionListener {
       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
           lblNylabel.setText("New label text");
       }
   }

   class YourClass {

       public void yourMethod() {
           ...
           btnNewButton.addActionListener(new MyActionListener());
       }
   }
   ```

   (only possible if the other class has access to the required variables.)
2. Same as above, but with an **inner (non-static) class**:

   ```
   class YourClass {

       public void yourMethod() {
           ...
           btnNewButton.addActionListener(new MyActionListener());
       }

       // Inner class
       class MyActionListener implements ActionListener {
           public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
               lblNylabel.setText("New label text");
           }
       }
   }
   ```

   (Here `lblNylabel` will probably be in scope for the inner class.)
3. Let the **enclosing class itself implement the `ActionListener`** and use `this` as argument to `addActionListener`:

   ```
   class YourClass implements ActionListener {

       public void yourMethod() {
           ...
           btnNewButton.addActionListener(this);
       }

       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
           lblNylabel.setText("New label text");
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Thank you for the helpful answer. Could you give some examples on how to do it without anonymous subclasses in a more "simple" manner? (Even if anonymous subclasses is considered a best practice)